# SQLite Comparing tables in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is there any method to compare tables (with the same properties of course) and return true if they are the same and false if not? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do this in Android Studio to get the result in your development environment or inside your app to perform some logic or show the result to your users in some way?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to do this to check if I have to update a listview of news after comparing old table vs the new one. Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly then, you want to do this check in logic in your app. This has nothing to do with Android Studio. It looks like someone else already removed the [tag:android-studio] tag and edited your question to clarify this. [tag:android-studio] should only be used for questions about the IDE itself, not for questions about code you are writing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly but it is realtively easy.

That is sqlite stores the SQL used to define the tables in the table sqlite_master (the schema).

For the simplest comparision of SQL to SQL (for column definitions) then you could use the following SQL:-

```
WITH tablenames(table1,table2) AS (SELECT 'table1' /*<<<<< change accordingly */,'table2' /*<<<<< change accordingly*/)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT substr(sql,instr(sql,'(')) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = (SELECT table1 FROM tablenames)) =
        (SELECT substr(sql,instr(sql,'(')) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = (SELECT table2 FROM tablenames))
    ,0)
;
```

In Android this could be done using (within a database helper ) :-

```
public boolean compareTable(String table1, String table2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String result_column = "result";
    boolean rv = false;
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("WITH tablenames(table1,table2) AS (SELECT ? ,? )" +
            "SELECT " +
            "COALESCE(" +
            "(SELECT substr(sql,instr(sql,'(')) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = (SELECT table1 FROM tablenames)) =" +
            "(SELECT substr(sql,instr(sql,'(')) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = (SELECT table2 FROM tablenames))" +
            ",0) " +
            "AS " + result_column +
            ";",new String[]{table1,table2});
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = (csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(result_column)) > 0);
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- Note this will consider the slightest difference in the SQL as failing the comparison

## Example

The Database Helper **DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE = "htmlstore";
    public static final String IDCOLUMN = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String HTMLCOLUMN = "html";

    public static final String TABLE2 = "otherstore";
    public static final String TABLE3 = "storeother";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_htmlstore_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + "(" +
                IDCOLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                HTMLCOLUMN + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_htmlstore_table);
        String crt_otherstore_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2 + "(" +
                IDCOLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                HTMLCOLUMN + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_otherstore_table);
        String crt_storeother_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE3 + "(" +
                HTMLCOLUMN + " TEXT, " +
                IDCOLUMN + " INTEGER, " +
                " PRIMARY KEY(" + IDCOLUMN + ")" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_storeother_table);
    }


    public long insert(String html) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(HTMLCOLUMN,html);
        return db.insert(TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public String getHTML(long id) {
        String rv = "";
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE,new String[]{HTMLCOLUMN},IDCOLUMN+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(HTMLCOLUMN));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean compareTable(String table1, String table2) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String result_column = "result";
        boolean rv = false;
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("WITH tablenames(table1,table2) AS (SELECT ? ,? )" +
                "SELECT " +
                "COALESCE(" +
                "(SELECT substr(sql,instr(sql,'(')) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = (SELECT table1 FROM tablenames)) =" +
                "(SELECT substr(sql,instr(sql,'(')) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = (SELECT table2 FROM tablenames))" +
                ",0) " +
                "AS " + result_column +
                ";",new String[]{table1,table2});
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = (csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(result_column)) > 0);
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

- Note that effectively the 3 tables are all the same (**BUT** the 3rd table differs in the SQL used to generate the column definitions and will thus be considered different)
- COALESCE is used to convert a null (no such table(s) in sqlite_master) to 0 (false)

The invoking code **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Log.d("TABLECOMPARE"," Result = " + String.valueOf(databaseHelper.compareTable(DatabaseHelper.TABLE,DatabaseHelper.TABLE2)));
        Log.d("TABLECOMPARE"," Result = " + String.valueOf(databaseHelper.compareTable(DatabaseHelper.TABLE2,DatabaseHelper.TABLE3)));
        Log.d("TABLECOMPARE"," Result = " + String.valueOf(databaseHelper.compareTable(DatabaseHelper.TABLE,DatabaseHelper.TABLE3)));
        Log.d("TABLECOMPARE"," Result = " + String.valueOf(databaseHelper.compareTable(DatabaseHelper.TABLE,DatabaseHelper.TABLE)));
    }
}
```

## Result :-

```
2020-01-14 07:23:29.624 D/TABLECOMPARE:  Result = true
2020-01-14 07:23:29.625 D/TABLECOMPARE:  Result = false
2020-01-14 07:23:29.625 D/TABLECOMPARE:  Result = false
2020-01-14 07:23:29.626 D/TABLECOMPARE:  Result = true
```

i.e.

- Table1 and Table2 are considered the same
- Table2 and Table3 are considered different
- Table1 and Table3 are considered different
- Table1 is considered the same as table 1.

Comment: I don't know where my previous thanks comment gone, but thanks again.